# How to send I2C commands from Creality 4.2.2 board with Marlin

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin

I'm wondering if anyone has ever gotten the Ender 4.2.2 board to send I2C commands? I'm looking to add some extra features, and I2C seems the best way to do it. So far, I've reflashed Marlin with the `EXPERIMENTAL_I2CBUS` enabled and currently have broken out the SDA and SCL lines from the LCD to connect them also to an Arduino.

This seems to be working (ran a sniffing test and it printed some output), although it causes the screen to constantly think that it is being clicked. The Arduino takes address 10 and then I tried sending data over I2C with `M260 A10` but the Arduino received nothing. Just wanted to see if anyone had done this before and had any pointers?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? If it is a matter of debugging the code, *and* you have a second Arduino to hand, consider using the one-wire protocol, [debugWIRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DebugWIRE) - it is really useful if low level debugging is needed.